# how to implement openid support with classic asp?

Tags: iis, asp-classic, openid

I'd like to implement something like stackoverflow's login system in classic asp...

is it possible?

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 8):

[DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net:8000/) supports OpenID on classic ASP.  They've got a [sample classic ASP login page](http://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/blob/b49a8d68f890e2e5bd95d2475f106fa98463c43a/samples/OpenIdRelyingPartyClassicAsp/login.asp) as well.